# A normal Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I decided to practice my linked-list knowledge, and decided to create one in C++!

I ran this code on two different online compilers - one worked, and the other is giving me a segfault.  I cannot figure out what the problem is within my code, and am wondering if you can help me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *next;
    Node(int val){
        this->val = val;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node *head;

    void insertAtHead(Node *temp)
    {
        if (head == NULL) 
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }

    void printList()
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->val << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void insertAtBack(Node *temp)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            return;
        }

        Node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }

    void deleteNode(Node *temp)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Empty List";
            return;
        }
        if (head->val == temp->val)
        {
            head = head->next;
            return;
        }

        Node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            if (current->next->val == temp->val)
            {
                current->next = current->next->next;
                return;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node *temp = new Node(10);
    Node *temp2 = new Node(4);
    Node *temp3 = new Node(17);
    Node *temp4 = new Node(22);
    Node *temp5 = new Node(1);
    LinkedList x;
    x.insertAtHead(temp);
    x.insertAtHead(temp2);
    x.insertAtBack(temp3);
    // x.insertAtBack(temp4);
    // x.insertAtBack(temp5);
    // x.deleteNode(temp);
    x.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am encountering is when I use the `insertAtBack()` method.  It gives me a segfault, but I do not see what's wrong with the logic.  It is pretty straight forward. The `insertAtFront()` method works, but once I call `insertAtBack()` my code fails.

Comment: change `Node *head;` to `Node *head = NULL;`

Comment: "I decided to practice my linked list knowledge and decided to create one in C++! " - oh, why??? Why not actually use the list classes in  the C++ Standard Library to produce a useful program - you will learn a lot more by doing that than producing yet another awful linked list implementation.

Comment: I strongly recommend stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: *I decided to practice my linked list knowledge and decided to create one in C++* -- The problem is that you need to *know* C++ thoroughly to implement a linked list properly.  You need to know how to properly manage memory, not just the basics of a linked list that you will find in a text book.  If it were Java or C#, maybe, but C++ has that extra hurdle of proper memory management, rule of 3 or 5, etc.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - I think its perfectly fine to do this as an excercize in writing a utility class. Eventually OP will end up with an understanding of why things like generics, smart pointers,.... exist (I hope). For real linked lists of course OP should use std::list. Maybe a little ambitious for first c++ program

Answer (score 4):

make sure to initialize `Node *head` to `NULL`.

After insert `temp`(which is value 10), `temp->next` value becomes undefined value, because `Node *head` is undefined value.

Answer (score 2):

Your `LinkedList` class is not initializing its `head` member.  You need to add a constructor to initialize `head` to NULL.

Also, the class is leaking memory, as there is no destructor to free the nodes when a `LinkedList` instance is destroyed, and `deleteNode()` doesn't free the node being removed, either.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int val;
    Node *next;

    Node(int val) : val(val), next(NULL) { }
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;

    // if you are NOT using C++11 or later, add these
    // until you are reading to tackle copy semantics!
    /*
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &);
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList &);
    */

public:
    LinkedList() : head(NULL) {} // <-- add this!

    ~LinkedList() // <-- add this!
    {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current)
        {
             Node *next = current->next;
             delete current;
             current = next;
        }
    }

    void insertAtHead(Node *temp)
    {
        if (!head) 
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }

    void printList()
    {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current)
        {
            cout << current->val << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    void insertAtBack(Node *temp)
    {
        if (!head)
        {
            head = temp;
            return;
        }

        Node *current = head;
        while (current->next) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }

    void deleteNode(Node *temp)
    {
        if (!head)
        {
            cout << "Empty List";
            return;
        }

        if (head == temp)
        {
            head = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            return;
        }

        Node *current = head;
        while (current->next)
        {
            if (current->next == temp)
            {
                current->next = temp->next;
                delete temp;
                return;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    // if you ARE using C++11 or later, add these until
    // you are reading to tackle copy and move semantics!
    /*
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &) = delete;
    LinkedList(LinkedList &&) = delete;
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList &) = delete;
    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList &&) = delete;
    */
};

int main()
{
    Node *temp = new Node(10);
    Node *temp2 = new Node(4);
    Node *temp3 = new Node(17);
    Node *temp4 = new Node(22);
    Node *temp5 = new Node(1);

    LinkedList x;
    x.insertAtHead(temp);
    x.insertAtHead(temp2);
    x.insertAtBack(temp3);
    // x.insertAtBack(temp4);
    // x.insertAtBack(temp5);
    // x.deleteNode(temp);

    x.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

Which can then be simplified further:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int val;
    Node *next;

    Node(int val, Node *next = NULL) : val(val), next(next) { }
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;

    // if you are NOT using C++11 or later, add these
    // until you are reading to tackle copy semantics!
    /*
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &);
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList &);
    */

public:
    LinkedList() : head(NULL) {} // <-- add this!

    ~LinkedList() // <-- add this!
    {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current)
        {
             Node *next = current->next;
             delete current;
             current = next;
        }
    }

    Node* insertAtHead(int value)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node(value, head);
        if (!head) 
            head = temp;
        return temp;
    }

    void printList()
    {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current)
        {
            cout << current->val << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    Node* insertAtBack(int value)
    {
        Node **current = &head;
        while (*current)
            current = &((*current)->next);
        *current = new Node(value);
        return *current;
    }

    /*
    void deleteNode(Node *temp)
    {
        Node *current = head, *previous = NULL;
        while (current)
        {
            if (current == temp)
            {
                if (previous)
                    previous->next = temp->next;
                if (head == temp)
                    head = temp->next;
                delete temp;
                return true;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    */

    bool deleteValue(int value)
    {
        Node *current = head, *previous = NULL;
        while (current)
        {
            if (current->val == value)
            {
                if (previous)
                    previous->next = temp->next;
                if (head == temp)
                    head = temp->next;
                delete temp;
                return true;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // if you ARE using C++11 or later, add these until
    // you are reading to tackle copy and move semantics!
    /*
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &) = delete;
    LinkedList(LinkedList &&) = delete;
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList &) = delete;
    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList &&) = delete;
    */
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList x;
    x.insertAtHead(10);
    x.insertAtHead(4);
    x.insertAtBack(17);
    // x.insertAtBack(22);
    // x.insertAtBack(1);
    // x.deleteValue(10);

    x.printList();

    return 0;
}
```